# Copy value and than paste

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Below is also a copy of my code:

```
    <th scope="row" class="style1">test</th>
        <td id="result7" class="style1" style="width: 229px"></td>
        <td id="result8" class="style1" style="width: 229px"></td>
        <td id="result9" class="style1" style="width: 229px"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

And finally the JS is;

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use  $("#result1")............

Comment: Please elaborate. There's a reason the 30-character limit is there.

Comment: The. Answer doesnt take 30 characters

Answer (score 0):

You need to match on ID's **not classes**. Also, use `.text` not `.val`.

Try this:

```
$(function test() {
    $('#Result #result1').html($('#Data #val1').html());
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/G3tBT/79/

Comment: Surely it is better to use `.html()` rather than `.text()` due to potential HTML content, such as use of HTML entities??

Answer (score 0):

You are using the incorrect selector.  The dot (.) selector is for classes.  You are looking for an id, so you need to use the hash (#) selector.  Also, use `.text()` not `.val()`. Like this:

```
$('#Result #result1').text($('#Data #val1').text());
```

Answer (score 0):

seems like: more simply

```
$('#Result').find('#result1').text($('#Data').find('#val1').text());
```

NOTE ID must be unique SO take out the first reference

```
$('#result1').text($('#val1').text());
```

NOTE I would use classes instead of an ID if you have a lot of these.

Do one at a time: ( NOTE: Use html not text in case it has embedded stuff)

```
$('#Result').find('td.style1').eq(0).html($('#Data').find('td.style1').eq(0).html());
$('#Result').find('td.style1').eq(1).html($('#Data').find('td.style1').eq(1).html());
```

Do all of them:

```
$('#Data').find('td.style1').each(function(index){
    $('#Result').find('td.style1').eq(index).html($(this).html());
});
```

Comment: @MattyS80 probably what you REALLY need is the last one? - not knowing your use case I make assumptions perhaps but...

Comment: Ahh close Mark, it was the third one I ended up using :), thank you soo much its working great, but I just had another small question at the moment the result is copying to the table all scrunched up not displaying the line breaks, and putting all text on one line, is there any way to display it exactly like it is in the original table?

Answer (score 0):

`$("#Result #result1").html($("#Data #val1").html());`

In situations like this it is wiser to use `.html()` rather than `.text()` to deal with potential HTML content within the source such as HTML entities.